# How do I freeze columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I don't think I can freeze columns / rows. I want to freeze the first 2 columns in my excel spreadsheet. I have read that I would go to View -> Freeze panes. But I am not given that option.

When I go to "View", I am only given the options to "Unfreeze panes", "Freeze top row" and "Freeze first column". I am not given a drop down menu.

How do I do this?

Comment: based on my testing, your panes may already be frozen. Unfreeze them, then select the cell you want to freeze then freeze panes...

Comment: @gns100 it didn't work. I still only get the above options I mentioned

Comment: I promise you that it's what @gns100 says. The 'Freeze Panes' dropdown will only display 'Unfreeze Panes' as an option if you've already frozen panes. Unfreeze them, then freeze them where you want. See screenshots in gns100's answer.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot (of the whole excel window - just black out any data)?

Answer (score 2):

In desktop Excel, when my panes are frozen I get the menu that you describe:

[image]

When I don't have any panes frozen this is what the menu looks like:

[image]

I'm sorry, I'm not sure I can diagnose what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternative options :

1. Use **Split**, then you will see two lines that are a little thicker. You can move them around to your liking and the you can use **Freeze Panes** to set them in place.

   [image]
2. First you need to use **Unfreeze panes**! Ones this is done, it will give you the option to **Freeze Panes** the button's text will change.

   [image]

If none of the solutions work, there might be s.th. wrong with your button. Add a additional split button into the ribbon, in the selection menu use the one that has the small black arrow (sorry for the german screen shot.

[image]

If it still does not work you will need to provide more info, e.g. a screenshot, your excel version etc.